# openpyxl - set custom paper size for printing

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to set the paper size print option to **A6** or a **custom user size template** with `openpyxl`, the code would be as follows:

```
    workbook = Workbook()
    ws = workbook.active
    ws.page_setup.paperSize = ws.PAPERSIZE_CUSTOM
```

unfortunately, from the docs, it seems the only enumerated sizes available are:

```
PAPERSIZE_LETTER = '1'
PAPERSIZE_LETTER_SMALL = '2'
PAPERSIZE_TABLOID = '3'
PAPERSIZE_LEDGER = '4'
PAPERSIZE_LEGAL = '5'
PAPERSIZE_STATEMENT = '6'
PAPERSIZE_EXECUTIVE = '7'
PAPERSIZE_A3 = '8'
PAPERSIZE_A4 = '9'
PAPERSIZE_A4_SMALL = '10'
PAPERSIZE_A5 = '11'
```

I've tried setting the paper height and paper width to my custom properties as such:

```
    #ws.page_setup.paperSize = ws.PAPERSIZE_A6
    ws.page_setup.paperHeight = '105mm'
    ws.page_setup.paperWidth = '148mm'
```

however, when printing thru excel, I still have to use the drop down dialog to select 'A6' before I can print to the correct paper size.

Is there a way I can do this? or achieve a similar effect? I'm on Mac OS if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: set custom paper size for printing

*from the docs, it seems the only enumerated sizes available are ...*

> The missing values, from OpenOffice:
>
> - **A6**: `70`
> - **Custom**: `0`
>
> The values have to be of type `int`.

Tried to setting it using:

```
ws.page_setup.paperSize = 70
# or
ws.set_printer_settings(70, ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
```

does not change <kbd>Format</kbd> => <kbd>Page</kbd> => `[Page]` settings.

---

This works for me:

```
ws.page_setup.paperHeight = '105mm'
ws.page_setup.paperWidth = '148mm'
```

The <kbd>Format</kbd> => <kbd>Page</kbd> => `[Page]` setting are changed to `User:` with the given `Height/Width`.

> **I recommend to use the following**:

```
ws.set_printer_settings(0, ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
ws.page_setup.paperHeight = '105mm'
ws.page_setup.paperWidth = '148mm'
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2 - openpyxl: 2.4.1 - LibreOffice: 5.2.7.2***

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but no luck with `openpyxl-3.0.0`, in excel the print dialog just defaults to `US Letter` for unknown enumeration `0`. Though, `70` works for `A6`, which helps for one of my use cases.

Comment: @randomfigure: ***"print dialog just defaults to US Letter"***: Confirm that, tried `ws.page_setup.usePrinterDefaults = False` without success.

Comment: yes, I have tried `ws.page_setup.usePrinterDefaults = False` but it causes my other settings such as `scale` and `orientation` to be ignored/reset.

Comment: Excel also stores printer-specific settings as BLOBs in an Excel file: these are completely opaque to openpyxl.

Comment: @CharlieClark: Thanks for that info, could we consider, it's out of control for any 3trd party `XLSX` tool.

Comment: Yep, like actual macro code. It's also OS specific. AFAIK page settings are for Excel's internal use only, which is why it has its own preview panes.